# Prove: The relation $v_i\mathcal{R}v_j\iff v_i\;\text{is adjacent to}\; v_j$ is not reflective or transitive or antisymmetric

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory, relations

> Prove that the relation $\mathcal{R}$ defined on the set of vertices of a graph such that $$v_i\mathcal{R}v_j\iff v_i\;\text{is adjacent to}\; v_j$$ is not necessarily:
>
> 1. Reflexive.
> 2. Transitive.
> 3. Antisymmetric.

---

Remember that a graph is a $3$-tuple $G=(V,A,\varphi)$ where $V\neq\emptyset$ is the set of vertices, $A$ is the set of edges and $\varphi\colon A\to V^{(2)}$ is the incidence function, where $V^{(2)}$ represents the set consisting of subsets of $1$ or $2$ elements of $V$.

Also, two vertices are *adjacent* if there exists a $a_k\in A$ such that $\varphi(a_k)=\{v_i,v_j\}$. That is, they are vertices that are joined by some edge.

With this, I tried the following:

1. Let $G_1=(\{v_1,v_2\},\{a_1\},\varphi)$ where $\varphi(a_1)=\{v_1,v_2\}$:

   [image: First graph]

   We have $\mathcal{R}=\{(v_1,v_2)\}$ but it is not reflexive.
2. Let $G_2=(\{v_1,v_2,v_3\},\{a_1,a_2\},\varphi)$ where $\varphi(a_1)=\{v_1,v_2\}$ and $\varphi(a_2)=\{v_1,v_3\}$:

   [image: Second graph]

   We have $\mathcal{R}=\{(v_1,v_2),(v_1,v_3)\}$ i.e. $v_2\mathcal{R}v_1$ and $v_1\mathcal{R}v_3$ but $v_2\!\not\!\!\mathcal{R}v_3$.
3. Let $G_3=G_1$. We have that $v_1\mathcal{R}v_2$ and $v_2\mathcal{R}v_1$ but $v_1\neq v_2$.

**Is my proof correct?**

Comment: Yes. If a graph have a vertex that have no loops the relation fails to be reflexive. Distinct adjacent vertices testifies failure of anti-symmetry (in fact, the relation is symmetric) and you're graph 2 is the very triple of elements that negates transitivity.

Comment: You write that edges are sets of one or two vertices, but later you write the tuple notation $(v_1, v_2)$ but mean sets (otherwise you would have to add $(v_2, v_1)$ to $R$ for $G_1$.

Comment: Generally relations are defined as sets of tuples of the same cardinality, not sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $(3)$ I would change the statement $$G_1=G_3$$ because  they are not quite the same.

You may provide a different graph for part $3$ to inhance  your solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! Why they are not quite the same? I picked $G_3$ to be the same as $G_1$. Why does $G_1$ (or $G_3$ it is the same) fullfill the transitive property?

Comment: In $G_3$ you have  used two edges while in $G_1$ you have only one.

Comment: I think in $G_3$ I did not use two edges but two vertices, the same as in $G_1$. Note that in $G_1$ (or $G_3$) $v_1\mathcal{R}v_2$ because there exists a $a_1\in A$ such that $\varphi(a_1)=\{v_1,v_2\}$, and $v_2\mathcal{R}v_1$ because there exists a $a_1\in A$ such that $\varphi(a_1)=\{v_2,v_1\}$. However, clearly $v_1\neq v_2$. Where am I wrong? Thank you again.

Comment: Oh, are you saying that I am using the hypothesis of symmetry when I could not use it? If so, what would be your $G_3$ so we cannot use the symmetry property?

Comment: I would say: Let $G_3=(\{v_1,v_2\},\{a_1,a_2\},\varphi)$ where $\varphi(a_1)=\{v_1,v_2\}$ **and** $\varphi(a_2)=\{v_2,v_1\}$ (we add to $G_1$ one edge from $v_2$ to $v_1$). Then it is true that $v_1\mathcal{R}v_2$ and $v_2\mathcal{R}v_1$, but $v_1\neq v_2$. Now it is correct (3)?

Comment: Since your graphs are not directed you are correct and the proof is fine

Comment: Sorry but what proof is correct? The proof in the question or the proof in the comments?

Comment: The proof in the comment.